# DART nodes.add() to add multiple copies of an element

Tags: dart

I have a list of items I want to display thumbnails for.  However, if any of the thumbnails are recorded as missing, I want to display a 'missing image' image.  The list might be long, so I would like to reuse the same 'missing image' whenever it is needed.

However, the test code below results in only one copy of the image - the last one added.  My question: how can I add one Element multiple times without having to do a new() each time?

```dart
ImageElement img = new ImageElement();
img.src= "http://myserver/missing.png";  
...
div.nodes.add(img);    
div.appendText('11111');
div.nodes.add(img);    
div.appendText('22222');
div.nodes.add(img);    
div.appendText('33333');
```

Comment: It seems like a Dart feature of being able to declare the img as 'final' dynamically, i.e. after it has loaded, could be part of the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that code you are not adding a new image to the `div` element. The `div.nodes.add(img)` actually appends the `img` as last node under the `div` element (`nodes.add(node)` uses a [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) under the hood).

To make it work, you have to create a new `ImageElement` for each `div.nodes.add(img)`. You can also use [Node.clone()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Node.html#clone) to create a new `ImageElement`.

Something like the following in your case :

```dart
final img = new ImageElement(src:"http://myserver/missing.png");
div.nodes.add(img.clone(false));
div.appendText('11111');
div.nodes.add(img.clone(false));
div.appendText('22222');
div.nodes.add(img.clone(false));
div.appendText('33333');
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  But... it seems so wasteful... is it impossible to grab a pointer to the actual bitmap, and stick that into the new element each time (thereby avoiding many copies of the same bitmap occupying RAM)?

Comment: That's not a Dart specific issue but it relays on how browsers handle DOM rendering and resources loading. And I hope/believe the browsers make that quite well.